# Virtualbox, dkms, linux-header and virtualbox-dkms installed, but said to be missing?

Tags: debian, software-installation, virtualbox, bunsenlabs

I am trying to install virtualbox on a BunsenLabs (Debian) system.

I validated that I have everything installed:

```
$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') virtualbox dkms virtualbox-dkms
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
dkms is already the newest version.
linux-headers-amd64 is already the newest version.
virtualbox is already the newest version.
virtualbox-dkms is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

(To be upgraded package is `openjre-8-headless`).

However, when I start `virtualbox`:

```
$ virtualbox 
WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist.
     Please install the virtualbox-dkms package and the appropriate
     headers, most likely linux-headers-amd64.

     You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
```

Reinstalling everything, reconfigureing everything either.

Trying to force the creation of the device fails too:

```
$ sudo modprobe vboxdrv
modprobe: FATAL: Module vboxdrv not found.
```

Should I just create the device manually? What other options do I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After uninstalling the debian's version of `virtualbox` and `virtualbox-dkms`, I added [Oracle's repository](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads):

```
#Add the repository
sudo echo "deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian jessie contrib" > /etc/apt/source.list.d/virtualbox.list
#Add the key
curl https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc
sudo apt-key add oracle_vbox_2016.asc
```

Then installed the `virtualbox-5.1` package, which work fine.

Source: User WeblionX of the freenode's #virtualbox IRC channel.